# Vim abbreviation using colon?

Tags: vim

I want to do some abbreviations that contain colons, but it doesn't work in vimrc:

```
ab t:u unsigned
```

I get a syntax error. I tried `\:` and `\\:\` but it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with vim's keyword recognition. Maybe it is a bug or not. Inserting `:` to the list `iskeyword` will make the abbreviation of yours possible. But it can cause unexpected side effects navigating your C.

Other possibility is to check `snipMate` or other similar plugin to provide templates.